# How to change page title in navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the text in my navigation bar depending on the content.

In my App.jsx file I have my routes as well as the navigation bar. Following a route should change it's text accordingly.

The quick and dirty solution of just copying the navbar into every component would definitely work, but I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: if you are using `react-router` you can use `useLocation` and `useParams` hooks.  
read more in this link: https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr. A said, you can have your Navbar component query for current page that is opened, via useLocation or useParams, and conditionally show different information.
This can be achieved by having an array of objects where you store given text for given page, such as

```
NAVBAR_TEXTS = [{page:"/", text: "Main page"}, {page:"/info", text: "Info page"}]
```

etc.
Then the text in the navbar would be

```
const location = useLocation();

const textToShow = NAVBAR_TEXTS.find(el => el.page === location.pathname)?.text
```